# Unresolved reference arraylist : java.util vs kotlin.collections import issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin, import

ArrayList in the below code gives unresolved reference. The IDE recommends
possible import solution import of java.util.arraylist. This does not resolve the issue.

I checked the source website code and  kotlin.collections arraylist import will fix the issue. Somehow the latter import is not showing up in project files.

What import library am I missing? Only java dependency is being shown in the autocomplete and kotlin one is missing. The source github url is linked below for build.gradle file if needed.

CharactersAdapter.kt

```
class CharactersAdapter(private val listener: CharacterItemListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CharacterViewHolder>() {

    interface CharacterItemListener {
        fun onClickedCharacter(characterId: Int)
    }

    private val items = ArrayList<Character>()

    fun setItems(items: ArrayList<Character>) {
        this.items.clear()
        this.items.addAll(items)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

https://github.com/sberoch/RickAndMorty-AndroidArchitectureSample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`kotlin.collections.ArrayList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/) is the import you're looking for. Make sure `kotlin-stdlib` is on your classpath - recent versions of the Kotlin Gradle plugin should be adding that dependency automatically.

Comment: apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
and     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
is added in the gradle build but the import doesn't show up.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't show up in the auto-complete menu? What happens if you try to add it manually and build the project?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't show up in autocomplete menu. I try to add it manually, it gives compile errors. Modifying the build gradle with removing  ' dataBinding{
    enabled = true
}' resolved the issue. I had added that earlier and removed it to solve the issue.